# Is there a specific term for siblings of mutiple pregnancy, regardless of the number of children?

Tags: word-request

We can use twins for two children, triplets if they are three, but is there a generic term for such siblings born together, regardless of their number?

Comment: As you'll see from [this question as asked on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314606/word-for-relationships-between-triplets), English doesn't have a "normal, conversational-level" hyperrnym for sibling twins, triplets, quads... If any such term *did* exist, you can be quite sure ***triplets*** would use it when introducing just one of their siblings to someone. But it doesn't, so the best they can do is say *I'd like you to meet my **triplet** Jane*. There might be a "medical" term, but for most normal contexts, it wouldn't be suitable anyway (being effectively "unknown").

Comment: In principle, Googling **define "coeval sibling"** should have produced useful results. But most of what I found was to do with cannibalism among coeval sibling ***fish**!*

Comment: @FumbleFingers There’s no word for them in Korean too.